# Making a hash table of iterators in C++

Tags: c++, hash, c++11, iterator

I'm trying to accelerate a specific linked-list operation by hashing some of the node pointers. This is the code I'm using:

```
unordered_set< typename list< int >::iterator > myhashset;
```

In Visual Studio 2012, I get an "error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type", since the compiler doesn't know how to hash iterators. Therefore, I need to implement my own hash function for list iterators like so:

```
struct X{int i,j,k;};

struct hash_X{
  size_t operator()(const X &x) const{
    return hash<int>()(x.i) ^ hash<int>()(x.j) ^ hash<int>()(x.k);
  }
};
```

([wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unordered_associative_containers_%28C++%29#Custom_hash_functions))

I'm having trouble figuring out what members of the iterator guarantee uniqueness (and, therefore, the members that I want to hash). Another concern is that those members may be private.

One solution that comes to mind is re-implementing  and list::iterator, but that seems like a hack and introduces more code to maintain.

Comment: That's no iterator! Your future, shrouded is. Iterators, confused are. hashing [iterators] leads to anger, anger leads to hate, hate leads to gdb.

Comment: @kfsone: I don't particularly like iterators either (after implementing one). Sometimes I miss the days of writing good old C. I don't see any alternatives to iterators in C++, though.

Comment: option a) I close my stackoverflow account, option b) I reply "the force be with (*youIt)".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the address of the element that the iterator refers to.

```
struct list_iterator_hash {
    size_t operator()(const list<int>::iterator &i) const {
        return hash<int*>()(&*i);
    }
};
```

But this will only work for dereferenceable iterators, not `end()` or `list<int>::iterator()`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The iterator may be passed by value, but the address is of the thing it's *pointing to*.

Comment: Do you need more parenthesis there?  `return hash<int*>()(&*i);` worked better for me.

Comment: @Eyal yes, you do. I added that in with an edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pointers to the element in place of iterators. Let's say you had a list of structs `MyStruct`. You can use

```
unordered_set<MyStruct*> myhashset;
```

and the C++ standard library already implements [`std::hash` for any pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash).

So if you ever need to insert or search `listIt` then use `&(*listIt)` which will get the pointer of type `MyStruct*`.